# Compiler keeps throwing AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python, for-loop, append, mean

I am writing a program that takes an input of several numbers and then puts the inputted numbers in a list. The program then finds and outputs the mean average of all of the numbers in the list to the console. Whenever I run this program, I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`.

What is causing this error?

```
episode_list= []

mather= input("Enter list:")

for number in mather:
    episode_list= episode_list.append(number)

for element in episode_list:
    total += element

final= total/ len(episode_list)

print(final)
```

Comment: `list.append` appends to the list and returns `None`, doing `episode_list = episode_list.append(number)` appends to the list then assigns the variable to `None` hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your first `for` loop with:

```
for number in mather:
    episode_list.append(number)
```

`list.append` does the append operation on `list` in place and returns `None`.

Also, in your second `for` loop, you need to do:

```
for element in episode_list:
    total += int(element)
    #        ^ Type-cast the value to `int` type
```

Answer (score 1):

`episode_list.append(number)` alone is enough

And that is because list.append is done in-place.